# Sitecore user cannot load items in editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I have a content editor that, when she logs into the Sitecore content editor and clicks an item, nothing happens. The item doesn't load for editing. If she clicks off of the item to another item she's prompted "do you want to save the changes to the item"?

Logging in with another account resolves the issue. Logging in with her account on another PC resolves the issue.

Has anyone ever seen this before? Sitecore is non-functional on this user's PC.

Comment: What browser is she using? Sounds like a javascript or browser incompatibility issue..

Answer (score 0):

When you say that the item doesn't load for editing, you need to be more specific?  Obviously, if she's clicking off the item and getting prompted to save, then the user is able to edit the item.  What is it that she can't do?

Also, it depends on what role you have the user set to use, but depending on how you have your site configured, a user can simply click the item, see the fields and enter content in them.  There may not be any "edit" queue.  Is this not the case?  If not, then there's more details that are needed to properly answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a browser / caching issue. I usually try the following. 
1. If IE 9 the I try and open a session in private and try again
2. Clear all browser history 
3. If that doesn't work try with another browser. 
4. If other browser fixes the issue then try to reset the original browser's settings to the defaults.

Last check if you are using a proxy server and try without. This is a long shot.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Sitecore is being used? Older versions using IE9 require compatibility mode to be enabled (this was resolved in later updates of 6.5)

I find the Content Editor most stable in Firefox and IE9 compatibility mode.  Chrome has a few finicky issues but generally works.